# Compilation error on an Oracle Database Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, ora-00923

I have been trying to compile this trigger for my table and I keep on getting this error:

***Error message*** :

```
 Compilation failed, line 4 (19:39:58) The line numbers associated with
 compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This
 only affects the compilation of database triggers. PL/SQL: ORA-00923:
 FROM keyword not found where expected

 Compilation failed, line 4
 (19:39:58) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are
 relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the
 compilation of database triggers. PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

This is my ***Trigger*** :

```
Create or Replace Trigger NEWSALARY 
  before insert or update on CREW
  for each row
Declare 
  v_emphours AIRPLANE. EMPWORKINGHOURS%TYPE;
Begin
  select EMPWORKINGHOURS into v_ emphours 
    from "AIRPLANE" 
   where  AIRPLANEID =:NEW."AirPlaneID";
  if v_emphours > 8 then 
   :NEW."Salary":= :NEW."Salary"* 50;
  end if;
End;
```

​

Answer (score 2):

there's a space in declaration part(grey one character-length area below)

> v_emphours AIRPLANE.EMPWORKINGHOURS%TYPE;

and here

> v_emphours

get rid of those spaces and removing useless quotations, you may run this statement without error :

```
create or replace TRIGGER  NEWSALARY 
before insert or update on CREW
for each row
Declare 
v_emphours AIRPLANE.EMPWORKINGHOURS%TYPE;
BEGIN
select EMPWORKINGHOURS into v_emphours from AIRPLANE Where  AIRPLANEID =:NEW.AirPlaneID;
if 
v_emphours > 8
then 
:NEW.Salary:= :NEW.Salary* 50;
END IF;
End;
```